# How to design multithreaded GUI-network application?

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface

I'm working on a small utility application in Python.

The networking is gonna send and receive messages. 
The GUI is gonna display the messages from the GUI and provide user input for entering messages to be sent.
There's also a *storage* part as I call it, which is gonna get all the network messages and save them in some kind of database to provide some kind of search later.

What my question is, what would be the best way to design this? For sure all them have to happen in separate threads, but what I'm wondering is how to pass information between them the best way? What kind of signal passing / thread locking available in Python should I use to avoid possible problems?

Comment: Is there a strict requirement to use python or are you open to other languages? Tcl and Tk, for example, can do all the above easily without the need for threads. And to me, no threads means less complexity which is always a Good Thing.

Comment: I'm using an api-library to communicate with remote network services there... the API i got implemented in python and c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you could use a [Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) for passing messages between the GUI and the network threads.

As for GUI and threads in general, you might find the [PyGTK and Threading](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2006/07/pygtk_and_threading.html) article interesting.

Answer (score 2):

One, probably the best, solution for this problem is to use [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/). It supports all the GUI toolkits.